# I cant import headers for Facebook integration in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I working on facebook integration in ios 5.1 I added FacebookSDK.framework  as follows if i want add social.framework  not in ios 5.1 build phases . anyone can solve this problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make Social.framework "optional" from where you added the framework. That will make available with iOS6 and later

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

without space .

Answer (score 0):

social. framework is a framework so you must to inport in < > this. not in "dubbel cote". try to using in <> this or if not then show what is error msg.?